# what are the differences of test frameworks ( NUnit,Mole,TestDriven)?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, nunit

this is so important question for me? I'm so confused. i have some knowledge and experiance on Nunit. This is so clear. But i think that it is not enough. it is my feeling. i have been making some research on Test method. i face to face too choices.

1) Mock

2) RhinoMock

3) SpecFlow

4) TestDriven

5) Vs Unit Testing FrameWork

6) Pex-Mole

7) Gallio

8) NUnit

is it enough? which one is useful? Or how to  choose according to what? Forexample; i guess Gallio is different from NUnit or SpecFlow more profesional than other. But they are my guess. Can you give some advises how to choose? How to prefer? or is there any preferences of you?

Comment: Pretty vague, an answer to all of this would be a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gallio and TestDriven are unit test runners, not frameworks.

Pex is a white-box tester, it analyses the code and automatically generates unit-tests for edge cases.

Mole is a kind of a mocking framework. Mock and Rhino Mocks are mocking frameworks.

The only unit testing frameworks here are NUnit, MSTest (what you call "Vs Unit Testing FrameWork") and SpecFlow, with NUnit and MSTest being the only "traditional" unit testing frameworks and SpecFlow being a BDD-style testing framework.

So, your list contains a lot of different things, maybe you should repeat your research.

<sub>I posted this as an answer as it was becoming too long for a comment</sub>

Comment: Thanks. But can you describe : Pex is a white-box tester, it analyses the code and automatically generates unit-tests for edge cases.

Comment: What don't you understand here?

Comment: More info or simple sample :)

Comment: Why don't you read the [documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/)?